# How to join elements of HashSet into a String with a delimiter

Tags: rust

I can do the following:

```
fn main() {
    let vec = vec!["first", "last"];
    println!("{}", vec.join(", "));
}
```

It gives this output:

> first, last

If I try to use `join` with a map type, it fails:

> error[E0599]: no method named `join` found for type `std::collections::HashSet<&str>` in the current scope

Answer (score 9, accepted):

More efficiently, you can [use itertools](https://crates.io/crates/itertools) to join an iterator without collecting it into a `Vec` first:

```
extern crate itertools;

use std::collections::HashSet;
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let hash_set: HashSet<_> = ["first", "last"].iter().collect();

    // Either of
    println!("{}", hash_set.iter().join(", "));
    println!("{}", itertools::join(&hash_set, ", "));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can convert a `HashSet` into an `Iterator`, collect it and then use `.join()`:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let mut books = HashSet::new();

    books.insert("A Dance With Dragons");
    books.insert("To Kill a Mockingbird");
    books.insert("The Odyssey");
    books.insert("The Great Gatsby");

    println!("{}", books.into_iter().collect::<Vec<&str>>().join(", "));
}
```

You could do the same with a `HashMap` - you would just need to extract its `.keys()` or `.values()` first, depending on which you want to join.

Comment: Curious why join isn't implemented for HashSet.

Comment: @Tshepang it's probably because `HashMap` and `HashSet` don't necessarily contain strings and even if they do, they are unordered.

Comment: Oh, didn't think of the ordered-ness of it all.

Comment: @ljedrz A `Vec` doesn't necessarily contain strings either :-) I think the ordering is the more pertinent concern.